# Get the filename of a php file without the extension and without the full url

Tags: php, url

I could only find such a way that involved entering directories and stuff but what I want is so I can get the php filename (no extension or directory info) and use it as a var anywhere in any folder (using the include function to include the var).

Comment: Dont do it!!!! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: please help, I am a newb, call me an idiot all you want but I want to learn.

Comment: I just want the php filename and i want to _hide_ the directory, I dont use cookies, I use sessions. tnx anyway @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @Lawrence: There are ways to easily do this without the risk of a directory traversal attack. ctrahey's answer is one such method.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté $bname = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$name = rtrim($bname, '.php'); And I don't see why my post deserves -1?

Comment: @MuqMan: That approach is safe, but there are problems with your implementation. See my comments on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$name = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

But please head the advice of commenter above :-)

Comment: No prob... And welcome to SO. Keep in mind that askers and answerers benefit from accepts and votes :-)

Comment: srry, i need someone to help me get 15 repu so i can vote. then i'll +1 u

Answer (score 0):

```
$bname = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$name = rtrim($bname, '.php');
```

That's what works for me.

Comment: The reason I did not post this as an answer is that it is fragile; and not portable; php may be parsed from files with ANY extension. The solution in my answer will work regardless of the extension.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. That's not how [`rtrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) works. If you have a script named `graph.php`, you would end up with `$name = 'gra'`. Use ctrahey's answer or use `substr($name, 0, strrpos($name, '.'))` to remove the last extension (files can have multiple extensions).

Comment: Ok, based on what you are saying, I will use your answer, it's just that it worked for me.